# refreshable javafx ReadOnlyProperty

Tags: java, javafx-2

Say that i have a boolean property that should represent the fact that a specific file inside a specific path exists or not.

Here is some code:

```
class SomeClass {

protected static final File FILE_TO_TEST = new File("test.canc.me");

//My javafx property
public ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase fileExistingProperty = new ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase() {

    @Override public boolean get() {
        return FILE_TO_TEST.exists();
    }

    @Override public Object getBean() { return null; }

    @Override public String getName() { return ""; }

};

//old style property property 
public boolean isFileExisting() {
    return fileExistingProperty.get();
}
```

Ok. The fact is that this property is read only since it cannot be set, its value depends of the "external" condition represented by the file to be existent in the application home. 
Yet, i need to refresh the property, that is look again to see if the file still exsist or not, and raise change and invalidation events accordingly. 
I could easily add a refresh method to the property class, but in order to call it, **i would have to create an inner class and not just an anonyous one.** 
And i would need an anonymous class for each different type of read-only-yet-refreshable property, that is boolean, String, Integer etc. 
The question is: is there a more convenient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

> i would have to create an inner class and not just an anonyous one.

I would go down this approach rather than try to create a bunch of anonymous inner classes.

> And i would need an anonymous class for each different type of read-only-yet-refreshable property, that is boolean, String, Integer etc.

Use generics - that's what they're designed for! Create a `ReadOnlyRefreshableProperty<T>`, then the return types and parameters of the relevant methods all use `T` as their type, removing the need for a separate class for each type.